# Appending text to a cell above another cell with specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find see how I can do this in excel vba. 
Basically my data set looks like this.

```
Dan (Cell A1)
Red (Cell A2)
Jim (Cell A3)
Red (Cell A4)
Tim (Cell A5)
Red (Cell A6)
```

I want to write a vba code that basically identifies cells above containing value "red" (If value Like "*Grade*" Then), in this case the names like Dan and Jim and append to those cells by adding : at the end of those cells.
End state should look like

```
Dan: (Cell A1)
Red (Cell A2)
Jim: (Cell A3)
Red (Cell A4)
Tim: (Cell A5)
Red (Cell A6)
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula.  In a new column, say `B`, put this in `B1` and drag down:

```
=IF(A2="Red",A1&":",A1)
```

[image]

If VBA is required, just loop over each cel and check the value below:

```
Sub replace()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A6")
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Offset(1, 0) = "Red" Then cel.Value = cel.Value & ":"
Next cel
End Sub
```